# calloc initializes more memory than available

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, calloc

This is the piece of code. 
With N=70000 or more, the code proceeds to STEP1 and crashes with Segmentation Fault.
Instead, if i put e.g. N=50000, calloc returns NULL and the program exits returning 2.
So why with N=70000 calloc does not complain?
I've compiled this with both gcc and icc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    float *matrix1,*q,*matrix2;
    int i,j,n,N=70000;
    n = N+1;
    if( (q=calloc(n,sizeof*q)) == NULL ) return 1;
    if( (matrix1=calloc(n*n,sizeof*matrix1)) == NULL ) return 2;
    if( (matrix2=calloc(N*N,sizeof*matrix2)) == NULL ) return 3;

    //STEP1
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            matrix2[i*N+j] = i*N+j;
        }
    }

    //STEP2
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){  // raw
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++){ // column
            if(i==j){ matrix1[i+j*n] = 0; } //diagonal elements
            else {
                matrix1[i+j*n] = i+j*n;
                matrix1[j+i*n] = j+i*n;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Definitely use long int for i, j and N because int can't store values so big.

Comment: @Igor Even better: `size_t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are exceeding the allowable value range for some variables.

You have `int N=70000`. A `N*N` gives you an int as well, which overflows and gets 605032704 instead, a value which can perfectly be allocated on your system.

You should use `size_t` for calling `calloc()`. In this case, it is probably large enough for your system even if you have 64 bits.

Of course, even `size_t` might overflow, and, depending on your system, quite early. So you should take care not to exceed `SIZE_MAX` when assigning.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Right, added that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. If my system has 256 GB of ram and I wish to use them all, how can i call `calloc()` to allocate such array?

Comment: Forget it, by using size_t it works just fine!! Thanks!